# Deeper understanding about how Realm works?

Tags: java, android, realm

**Q1 :** Please let me know what is different between two ways of `implementation` in below (about get `realm instance`). I want to know which one is faster, lighter in memory and what is recommended ?

**1. Set and Get Realm as Default (with specific config)**

```
private void setupCustomRealm() {
        if (!Utils.isStringHasText(databaseName)) {
            databaseName = DbManager.getInstance().getCurrentDb();
        }
        // get config
        RealmConfiguration config = getRealmConfigByDBName(databaseName);
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
        Realm.compactRealm(config);

    }

public Realm getCustomRealm() {
      if (firstTime) {
             setupCustomRealm();
      }
      return Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}
```

**2 .Get Realm from config directly**

```
public Realm getCustomRealm(Context context) {
        if (!Utils.isStringHasText(databaseName)) {
            databaseName = DbManager.getInstance().getCurrentDb();
        }
        // get config
        RealmConfiguration config = getRealmConfigByDBName(context, databaseName);
        Realm.compactRealm(config);
        return Realm.getInstance(config);
    }
```

**Q2 :**  In my application, now we are consider between 2 ways of implementation.

1: We create a new Realm instance every time when we need to do something with Database (in both of worker thread and UI thread) and close it when task get done.

2: We create only one instance of Realm and let it live along with application, when quit application we close instance above.

Please explain me the advantage and disadvantage of each one and which ways is recommended (My application using Service to handle database and network connection)

If I have 2 heavy tasks (take a long time to complete it's transaction), what is difference between execute 2 task by one Realm instance and execute 2 task on 2 Realm instances in 2 separate thread (I mean one thread have one Realm instances and instance will executes one in 2 tasks above), and which one if safer and faster.

what will happen if there is a problem while executing a transaction (example not responding or throws some exception)

Comment: I will answer this when I'm done with lunch (reply hook comment)

Comment: Great! I'm waiting for your answer!

Comment: I'm also linking the SO Realm docs because they're neat, I kept some of it up to date and stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/3187/realm#t=201608011053013386746

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I am not an official Realm person, but I've been using Realm for a while now.

Here's a [TL;DR version](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3229#issuecomment-236552238)

---

1.) It's worth noting a few things:

- A given Realm file should be accessed only with the same `RealmConfiguration` throughout the application, so the ***first*** solution here is preferable (don't create a new config for each Realm).
- `Realm.compactRealm(RealmConfig)` works only when there are **no open Realm instances on any threads**. So either at application start, or at application finish (personally I found that it makes start-up slower, so I call `compactRealm()` when my activity count reaches `0`, which I manage with a retained fragment bound to the activity - but that's just me).

2.) It's worth noting that `Realm.getInstance()` on first call creates a thread-local cache (the cache is shared among Realm instances that belong to the same thread, and increments a counter to indicate how many Realm instances are open on that given thread. When that counter reaches `0` as a result of calling `realm.close()` on all instances, the cache is cleared.

It's also worth noting that the `Realm` instance is thread-confined, so you will need to open a new `Realm` on any thread where you use it. This means that if you're using it in an IntentService, you'll need to open a new Realm (because it's in a background thread).

It is **extremely important** to call `realm.close()` on Realm instances that are opened on background threads.

```
Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    //do database operations
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Or API 19+:

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    //do database operations
}
```

- When you call `realm.close()` on a particular Realm instance, it invalidates the results and objects that belong to it. So it makes sense both to `open/close` Realms in Activity `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`, or open it within the Application and share the same UI thread Realm instance for queries on the UI thread.
- (It's not as important to close the Realm instance on the UI thread unless you intend to compact it after all of them are closed, but you **have to** close Realm instances on background threads.)

**Note:** calling `RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(appContext).build()` can fail on some devices if you call it in `Application.onCreate()`, because `getFilesDir()` can return `null`, so it's better to initialize your `RealmConfiguration` only after the first activity has started.

With all that in mind, the answer to 2) is:

- While I personally create a single instance of Realm for the UI thread, you'll still need to open (and close!) a new Realm instance for any background threads.
- I use a single instance of Realm for the UI thread because it's easier to inject that way, and also because `executeTransactionAsync()`'s `RealmAsyncTask` gets cancelled if the underlying Realm instance is closed while it's still executing, so I didn't really want that to happen. :)
- Don't forget, that you need a Realm instance on the UI thread to show `RealmResults<T>` from realm queries (unless you intend to use `copyFromRealm()` which makes everything use more memory and is generally slower)
- `IntentService` works like a normal background thread, so you should also close the realm instance there as well.

Both heavy tasks work whether it's the same Realm instance or the other (just make sure you have a Realm instance on that given thread), but I'd recommend executing these tasks serially, one after the other.

If there's an exception during the transaction, you should call `realm.cancelTransaction()` (the docs say begin/commit, but it always forgets about cancel).

If you don't want to manually manage begin/commit/cancel, you should use `realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() { ... });`, because it automatically calls begin/commit/cancel for you. Personally I use `executeTransaction()` everywhere because it's convenient.

Comment: I've also given a shorter and more concise answer on [Github Realm-Java issues](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3229#issuecomment-236552238)

Comment: do you know what kind of exception will be thrown when we try to compact realm while other instance still were not closed ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it doesn't throw an exception, it just returns false. It must be noted that encrypted Realms cannot be compacted. The `compactRealm()` call seems to consume any exception, and the message can be seen if you add a `RealmLog.add(new Logger() {...});` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Realm backend is based on LMDB? Is it open source like forntends?

Comment: @Maniero define which part of Realm you mean as "realm backend"

Comment: @EpicPandaForce C++ part. Code which is handling IO (mmap) and internal data structures.

Comment: @Maniero ah you can check that out in the Realm Core https://github.com/realm/realm-core